# Checking for type capabilities at function start

Tags: python, python-2.7, typechecking

I'm writing a set of python modules that are meant to be used internally. The issue that I am having users that are passing in subtly different parameter types that are required.

For example if something expects a list of lists, and is given a list of tuple, it will probably work most of the time, right up until the function tries to assign to an element of something it expects to be a list.

The problem that I am having is that sometimes it takes a long time for the function to reach the point where things start to go wrong, and when they do everything has to be restarted from scratch.

How can I test to see if something like `x[0][0]=null` or `x.myfunc(a,b)` will work if it either

1. Is expensive
2. Has side effects, like above

And get it to fail fast (if it would fail).

Note that I want to keep the duck typing nature of the code, so `isinstance()` and code don't work (or at least I don't see how)

Comment: Side effects are hard to test, so for the most part just refactor your code until it doesn't have any.  Outside of that, you're basically trying to solve the halting problem, so I wouldn't spend too much brainpower on it; just write your APIs as cleanly as possible and rely on the fact that we're all consenting adults.

Comment: @roippi ?? I want to know if a `x.myfunc(a,b)` will compile. I know that `myfunc` will have side effects. Pretty sure its not the halting problem...

Answer (score 0):

Duck typing doesn't necessarily always mean if it walks like a duck, treat it like a duck and check later to see whether it quacks. Doing it that way is often fine, but won't fail fast enough in your case.

If you wrote `foo`, then also write `foo_check` which takes the same arguments as `foo` but just checks the arguments, does very little and tries to leave things unchanged. Try to make it so that if `foo` would crash, then `foo_check` would also crash. Have `foo_check` do things like:

```
temp = x[0][0]
x[0][0] = temp
x[0].append('xxx')
x[0].pop()
```

Basically, whatever foo does with the arguments syntactically, `foo_check` should do once (and undo again, if appropriate). You may need to check whether objects are strings or lists. To do this, do whatever `foo` does that would crash if the wrong type is given.

If your `foo` calls your `bar`, then have `foo_check` call `bar_check`. Rename `foo` to `foo_optimized` and give your users a new `foo` which just calls `foo_check` and `foo_optimized`.

Put in your documentation e.g. "Your object `x` should have a method `myfunc` taking two arguments which, when called as `x.myfunc(-1, [])` will run without error but do nothing." Try to choose the null arguments so that most users will just naturally provide functions that work that way.  Then, your `foo_check` can call `x.myfunc(-1, [])`, so you will at least know whether`x.myfunc` can compile when called with two arguments.